# How to use Multidimenional array out of foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with Codeigniter,Right now i am fetching record from database,I m getting
data/array in following format (multidimensional/array inside array)

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23239
            [CategoryUrl] => restaurants
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23240
            [CategoryUrl] => restaurants
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23244
            [CategoryUrl] => restaurants
        )
 )
 ...
```

But i want to remove indexing(remove 0,1,2...) so for this i tried with following code
but showing me one array instead of all, In other words,i want to use array outside foreach loop
How can i do this ? Here is my code

```
$this->db->select("//select query with where condition")
$query = $this->db->get();  
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
            {
                $result = $query->result_array();
                $data=array();
                foreach($result as $rec)
                    {
                        $data['id']=$rec['id'];
                        $data['CategoryUrl']=$rec['CategoryUrl'];
                    }
                echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
            }
```

With use of above code i am getting following result ( only one instead of more than one),how can i get all ?

```
<pre>Array
(
    [id] => 23239
    [CategoryUrl] => restaurants
)
```

Comment: All data placed in `$result = $query->result_array();`. Not need foreach loop

Comment: What do you want the result to look like instead? You can't have duplicate keys in an array. Maybe you should use the ID as the key and the category as the value.

Comment: @Barmar :  i want to move data multidimensional to single array ( want to access outside foreach loop) how can i do this ?

Comment: @Lessmore: you are right but i dont need multidimensional array,I want single array, can i do this ?

Comment: You can't.  Indexes must be unique, so each time through the loop `$data['id']` etc.. overwrites the previous one so you will only ever have one. https://3v4l.org/VSvT9  Keep it the way it is from the DB, that's how it's done.

Comment: You can create a single-dimensional associative array like `[23239 => restaurants, 23240 => restaurants, 23244 => restaurants]`

Comment: @Barmar: How can i create ? because by default codeigniter giving multidimenional array

Comment: You loop through your array and assign the keys: `$data[$rec['id']] = $rec['CategoryUrl'];`

Comment: You can also use `$data = array_column(result, 'CategoryUrl', 'id');`

Comment: @Barmar: Can you write exact code so i can check and implement

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_column()` function to convert that 2-dimensional array to an associative array.

```
$this->db->select("//select query with where condition")
$query = $this->db->get();  
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $data=array_column($result, 'CategoryUrl', 'id');
    echo "<pre>";print_R($data);echo "</pre>";
}
```